# Finding area of related triangle and circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Let's say $AM$ and $AN$ are tangent lines to a circle centered at $O$. $L$ is a point on arc $MN$. Line $ML$ and $NL$ intersect with the line passing $A$ parallel to $MN$, at $P$ and $Q$. If $\angle POQ=45°$, prove that the area of circle $O$ is $2\pi$ times the area of $\triangle OPQ$.

[image]

I have discovered that points $ALMQ$ are concyclic, as well as points $ALNP$, but I cannot connect them with the asked area. I believe the problem can be solved using power of a point.

Comment: Very good, that construction takes more than just a compass and a straight edge. There is a fair amount of figuring to make sure that line QP passes through the intersections of tangents, radii and chord extensions, and is parallel with the chord spanning the tangent points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From power of $P$ with respect to circles $ALMQ$ and $MLN$ one gets:
$$
QA\cdot QP=QL\cdot QN=(OQ+r)(OQ-r),
$$
where $r$ is the radius of circle $MLN$. From power of $Q$ with respect to circles $ALNP$ and $MLN$ one gets:
$$
PA\cdot PQ=PL\cdot PM=(OP+r)(OP-r).
$$
Adding these two equations together one gets
$$
PQ^2=OP^2+OQ^2-2r^2,
\quad\hbox{that is:}\quad
OP^2+OQ^2-PQ^2=2r^2.
$$
On the other hand, from the cosine rule applied to triangle $OPQ$ one has:
$$
OP^2+OQ^2-PQ^2=2OP\cdot OQ{\sqrt2\over2}=4\,\text{Area}_{OPQ}.
$$
It follows that
$$
\text{Area}_{OPQ}={r^2\over2}.
$$